# Abstract not on the title page in revtex4-2 environment

Tags: titles, abstract

Recently, I have change my document class from Revtex 4.1 to revtex 4.2. This change cause my Abstract to move from the title page to a new page. This is my code.

```
\documentclass[superscriptaddress,aps,prd,showpacs,preprint]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subfig}

\newcommand{\fixme}[1]{\textcolor{red}}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}
    
\title{My Title}
\author{My Name}
\email{My Email}
\affiliation{My University}

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
    
    Abstract's Text.
    
\vspace{5mm}
    
{Keywords: Some Text}
    
\end{abstract}

\maketitle
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Everything is on one page for me.

Comment: Can you tell me which complier do you use? I use TeXstudio with MiKTeX.

Comment: Okay, so I try to reproduced the issue and find that if your Introduction is too short (or non-exist), then Abstract will appear as it should. The issue only happens when both Abstract and Introduction can't be on the first page together. The easy fix is done by adding \newpage after \maketitle.

Answer (score 3):

With {revtex4-2}, if you use \newpage after \maketitle, the abstract shows up on the title page and the entire text looks as expected.